# Better logic for firing events and doing the actual event?

Tags: python, events, logic

Below I have a simple class with some events in it.
Don't worry about the `Event` class, it's flawless.

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        # events
        self.e_hurt = Event()
        self.e_attack = Event()

    def hurt(self, damage):
        self.health -= damage
        self.e_hurt.fire()

    def attack(self, target):
        target.hurt(self.damage)
        self.e_attack.fire()
```

What I can't figure out is where to fire my events.
It makes most sense to fire `e_hurt` event after the warrior was hurt, and `e_attack` event after the warrior has attacked.
However, this results into `victim.e_hurt` getting fired before `attacker.e_attack`, when `attacker` attacks `victim`:

```
def on_hurt():
    print "Someone was hurt."

def on_attack():
    print "Someone attacked."

def main():
    victim = Warrior(50, 0)
    victim.e_hurt.subscribe(on_hurt)
    attacker = Warrior(50, 20)
    attacker.e_attack.subscribe(on_attack)
    attacker.attack(victim)
```

The two events get outputted in the "wrong" (programmatically correct, but semantically wrong) order:

```
 Someone was hurt.
 Someone attacked.
```

Obviously the warrior has to attack before the other warrior can get hurt.
Of course I could just change the `attack`-method to look like this:

```
def attack(self, target):
    self.e_attack.fire()
    target.hurt(self.damage)
```

But it doesn't feel right to raise an attack event before the actual attack happens, and some other events might need to be called after the attack.

The only actual solution I can think of is to have two events (`before_attack` and `after_attack`) but is there a better solution that wouldn't need two events for one actual event (attacking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def attack(self, target):
    self.e_attack.fire()
    target.hurt(self.damage)
```

seems to make perfect sense to me. `self` first attacks, then the `target` gets hurt.